# Pandas DataFrame exists in list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I tried searching but didnt see anything relevant, or it may have skipped my eyes.

So what I want is pretty specific. I have a list of Pandas DataFrame, and I want to check wheather the dataframe created in current step / workflow already exists in list, if yes then pass or else append to it. Now I tried using following:

```
if df not in best_dfs:
    # process something here
    best_dfs.append(df)
else:
   pass
```

This is how you would do to check weather a list contains some object of fixed type. But When I do the same, I recieve following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Projects/Barclays/Email Analytics/POC - Stop Cheque Classification/03_CodeBase/CodeBase/utils/FindBestDf.py", line 239, in <module>
print(obj.find_(dfs))
File "C:/Projects/Barclays/Email Analytics/POC - Stop Cheque Classification/03_CodeBase/CodeBase/utils/FindBestDf.py", line 19, in find_
r = self.__driver(list_of_df)
File "C:/Projects/Barclays/Email Analytics/POC - Stop Cheque Classification/03_CodeBase/CodeBase/utils/FindBestDf.py", line 201, in __driver
if v[0] not in best_dfs:
File "C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 1296, in f
return self._compare_frame(other, func, str_rep)
File "C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3670, in _compare_frame
raise ValueError('Can only compare identically-labeled '
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects
```

How do I tacke this? Any work around?

Any help will be grately appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you make a dict with a str as the key and the df as the value and check the str value? The issue here is that you're trying to compare a df for existence but the equality operator can only compare identically labeled dfs

Comment: Can you tell us more about these dataframes? Do they have the same size? Same number of columns? How are they unique?

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the most efficient way, but this works for pandas:

```
if not True in [df.equals(x) for x in df_list]:
    df_list.append(df)
```

Pandas has a [built-in method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html) to check for df equality called `df.equals()`. Basically you iterate this through your df_list to create another list of result, then check if any of the result return `True` (i.e. the same df exist in the list).

Comment: `not True in list` is equivalent to `any(list)`

Comment: Thanks @Yeile . This is exactly what I wanted. :-)